# jmeter thread group no of users assigned on running test plan stops incompletely

Tags: jmeter

Running a recorded test plan. I have assigned in Thread Group for No of users is 25, Ramp-up period is 25 and Loop Count is 1.

a).Start the test.
   b).While the test is running in the upper right-hand corner, the number gets increment 1 by 1 until 9/25. At some level, the number remains constant 9/25 and then shows 8/25. After some time, the number automatically gets decrements by 1, 7/25....0/25.
   c). In Database also, i seen the login entry only 9 users.

why my test plan not gets succeeded for the 25 users ? Please suggest me ?

Answer (score 0):

This is because - your test seems to be only 9 seconds long. ie. after 9th second, by the time the 10th thread is created, first thread finishes its execution. so it shows the concurrent user load on the server remains 9.

Remember that each thread/user is executed independently.

Lets assume - your recorded test plan takes 5 seconds to complete for an user/thread.

So, in your case,

second 1: user/thread 1 gets created & execution starts

second 2: user/thread 1 execution in-progress, user/thread 2 gets created & execution starts

second 3: user/thread 1 & 2 execution in-progress, user/thread 3 gets created & execution starts

second 4: user/thread 1,2 & 3 execution in-progress, user/thread 4 gets created & execution starts

second 5: user/thread 1,2,3 & 4 execution in-progress, user/thread 5 gets created & execution starts

second 6: user/thread 1 finished execution (5 seconds). user/thread 2,3,4 & 5 in progress. user/thread 6 gets created & execution starts

If you see, after 6th second, concurrent thread will be 5 because thread 1 already finished its execution.

If you need to see all the 25 users in 25 seconds (25/25) - then your test be taking more than 25 seconds.

(from your question - looks like your test is only 9 seconds long. so you can not expect 25 / 25 with 1 loop count)

Do the following:

```
Click the checkbox 'Forever' in the Loop count

Click the checkbox  'Scheduler'

Set the duration 60 seconds.
```

Run the test now - you will see 25 users in 25 seconds - the test will stop after 60 seconds. Scheduler will keep threads execute continuously for 60 seconds.

Hope it is clear.

Comment: Hi,Thanks.Now,its showing 25/25 at the right-top corner.why we should select both the option 'Forever' and 'Scheduler'(giving 60 seconds).why for ramp-up period?

Comment: one more issue.Only 15 login users/threads gets inserting in the database from out of 25 users. Above 15 users is not gets inserted into the database table. why ?

Comment: can you share more info on your table you are looking at /screenshot?

Comment: Database values will be SlotId : 3837245D-B11C-4644-955C-82985CE26B75 SessionId : njxymqb3mijm223t4mvvqaf5 CreatedOn : 2014-06-09 12:12:46.923 and UserMapId : 38. UserMapId value was the login user value.

Comment: No of threads : 20 Ramp-up Period : 100 . When i running my recorded test plan, while checking into the database only upto 15 users/threads log in & log out. why ? what i should do ? please let me know .  Above 15 users, i can't able to run my test plan .

Answer (score 0):

25 users in thread group doesn't always mean that you'll be having 25 concurrent requests.

There are several options on how you can implement your load scenario:

1. [Ultimate Thread Group](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/UltimateThreadGroup/) (available via [JMeter Plugins](http://jmeter-plugins.org/)) lets you specify number of users to start with, ramp up period, time to hold the load, ramp down period, etc. It looks like to be the easiest option to proceed with.
2. [Synchronizing Timer](http://blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeter-synchronizing-timer) - to release all threads at the same time, i.e. 25 requests at the same moment.
3. [Constant Throughput Timer](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Constant_Throughput_Timer) - to set the desired load, i.e. 25 requests per second.

Comment: What is "unable to load"? Do you see any errors for `jmeter.threads.JMeterThread` in jmeter.log?

Comment: where will the jmeter.log file located ? No of threads alloted 25. In database just inserting the login info just only for 15 threads.